# How to merge Grid.Column in Grid Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Good Day to everyone, I have Grid that has 4 columns I wanted to merge column#2 and and Column#3, like the picture below, But the problem is each entry is assign to specific Grid.Column. How do I achieve this? Thank you and Good Day. 
My Xaml Code:

```
    <ContentView Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <Grid RowSpacing="0">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Image Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Source="contact.png" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            />
      <Label Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"
             FontAttributes="Bold"
             HorizontalOptions="Start" 
             Text="Number:"
             TextColor="White" 
             VerticalOptions="Center"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            FontAttributes="Bold" 
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="Name:"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>

    <Entry  Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            IsEnabled="False"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="911"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Entry  Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            IsEnabled="False"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="Andreson Smith"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
     </Grid>
   </ContentView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set Grid.Column and Grid.ColumnSpan on the elements that you want to take up multiple columns:

```
<Entry  Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        IsEnabled="False"
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        Text="911"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

This Entry will start in column #2 and span 2 columns, thus "merging" columns #2 and #3 for this element.

Comment: this will do in Label but does not apply to <Entry> even if HorizontalOption is set to FillandExpand or CenterandExpand

Comment: I had forgotten about the initial value and the HorizontalOptions being set to Start, which will cause the Entry to take only enough space for the initial setting of Text or Placeholder. However setting HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" will cause the Entry to take both columns. Please post the updated code and screenshot of what you get with FillAndExpand and ColumnSpan.

Comment: you have to add <StackLayout Grid.Row Grid.Column Grid.ColumnSpan> thanks anyway I solve already :D